# jQuery click event only working after moving the mouse in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

So I know there are better ways of switching styles, but bear with me...

There seems to be a small bug happening on Chrome (but not Firefox) where the 'click' event wont do anything until the mouse has moved after the event.

```
$(function(){
    $('#selectsomething a[rel$=".css"]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('link.skeletor').attr('href', $(this).attr('rel')); 
    });
});
```

So if you click the link but don't move the mouse nothing happens... Do you think this may be a legitimate bug with Chrome or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I can't fathom why this got five upvotes. I also can't reproduce your problem. Can you create a stack snippet or jsFiddle that shows the problem? Here's mine that works fine in Chrome without having to move the mouse http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/e6k2zzsc/

Comment: As a side note, an anchor tag with a `rel` attribute containing a value ending with `.css` is invalid. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-rel): _"...this attribute specifies the relationship of the target object to the link object. The value is a comma-separated list of link types values..."_ A list of valid link types can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types).

Answer (score 0):

I don't why this shouldn't work (except the strange rel="" use).

If you are trying to use a minified or a version with multiple instances of the js the problem might be the usage of `.click` instead of the `.on('click', function(e))`.

To see an example of what i trying to say, [check out my Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/e6k2zzsc/3/)

For a full explanation on the difference between the two click functions check [this overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)