# jQuery click event only working after moving the mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm getting close to desperate here but I can't seem to find any solution to this. I basically have a problem with a click event that somehow acts as a *drag* event. Which is odd because, as far as I can tell, it really shouldn't.

Let me explain what's what. I have these simple radio buttons:

```
<div class="fruitButtons">
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="Apple">
    <label for="Apple">Apple</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="Banana">
    <label for="Banana">Banana</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="Citron">
    <label for="Citron">Citron</label>
</div>
<br><b>selected:</b>
<div class="status">none</div>
```

I use jQuery UI to transform these regular buttons into a nice looking buttonset via `$(".fruitButtons").buttonset();`.

Now I need the possibility to reset the buttonset, i.e. to uncheck all buttons at once. Since I don't want a separate reset button for that, I need the reset to happen when you click on an already checked button. To me, this is the most intuitive way to handle these radio buttons.

This is the (obviously simplified) way it's supposed to work:

```
$(function() {
    $(".fruitButtons").buttonset();
    var uncheck = apple = banana = citron = 0;

    $(".fruitButtons label").click(function(){
        var name = $(this).text();

        // see if button was previously checked
        // if yes set var 'uncheck' to 1
        if ((name == "Apple") && (apple)) uncheck = 1;
        if ((name == "Banana") && (banana)) uncheck = 1;
        if ((name == "Citron") && (citron)) uncheck = 1;
        apple = banana = citron = 0;

        if (!uncheck) {
            if (name == "Apple") apple = 1;
            if (name == "Banana") banana = 1;
            if (name == "Citron") citron = 1;

            // display name of currently checked button
            $(".status").text(name);
        }

        else {
            // unchecking the hidden input element
            $(this).prev().prop("checked", false);

            // resetting the buttonset to its initial state
            $(this).parent().buttonset("refresh");

            $(".status").text("none");
            uncheck = 0;
       }
    });
});
```

Check out the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6yx0rqjf/6/

But here's the problem: The unchecking process does not work properly. In fact, it only works when you actually *drag* the mouse while clicking, i.e. if you move the mouse a little while the mouse button is depressed.

Updating the `$(".status")` part works perfectly *every* time you click the button, but unchecking it is only succesful if you move the mouse a little.

How is this possible? Is this a bug? I was able to reproduce this behavior on Firefox 40.0.3 and Chrome 45.0.2454.85. I also found this unresolved question that may be somehow related:
[jQuery click event only working after moving the mouse in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334070/jquery-click-event-only-working-after-moving-the-mouse-in-chrome)

So, can anyone help me fix this? Is that even possible?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me in Chrome 44.0.2403.157.

Comment: It is not working in Chrome 44.0.2403.157.

Comment: I see. Changing the text to `None` works, but changing the style of the button doesn't.

Comment: Since this is working on jsFiddle, are you saying that it does not work in your code?

Comment: @Barmar Exactly. So, can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: @DawnGreen For me, it's neither working on jsFiddle nor in my code.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, I can reproduce it. You just didn't describe the problem clearly.

Comment: The click event is obviously working, since it's doing `$(".status")text("none")`. But something else is causing the button's state to change.

Comment: But does it work when you move the mouse while clicking? Or am I imagining things?

Comment: No, you're not imagining.

Comment: dactyL, since it is working for me on jsFiddle, I have to wonder if there is a problem with your browser.  Have you tried it on another machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're putting the click handler on the label, not the button itself. I moved it to the button, and adjusted the code, and it works correctly.

```
$(function() {

    var uncheck = apple = banana = citron = 0;

    $(".fruitButtons").buttonset();
    $(".fruitButtons :radio").click(function(){

        var name = $(this).next("label").text();

        // see if button was previously checked
        // if yes set var 'uncheck' to 1
        if ((name == "Apple") && (apple)) uncheck = 1;
        if ((name == "Banana") && (banana)) uncheck = 1;
        if ((name == "Citron") && (citron)) uncheck = 1;
        apple = banana = citron = 0;

        if (!uncheck) {
            if (name == "Apple") apple = 1;
            if (name == "Banana") banana = 1;
            if (name == "Citron") citron = 1;

            // display name of currently checked button
            $(".status").text(name);
        }

        else {
            // unchecking the hidden input element
            $(this).prop("checked", false);

            // resetting the buttonset to its initial state
            $(this).button("refresh");

            $(".status").text("none");
            uncheck = 0;
       }
    });

});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6yx0rqjf/10/)

Comment: Wow, thank you a lot, it works perfectly! I really don't remember why I put the click event on the label...